# Webform to add row to specific sql table

Tags: webforms, database

I have drupal running and have enabled a few modules including the webform module. I have opened phpmyadmin and added a new table with specific rows.

Now I want to link the two so that a user can log in to the site, fill out the webform with some data each day and I can insert a new row in the table and send each field to a specific column in that row. Later I will build a page for the user to view his inputs, maybe with graphs etc.

Am I on the right track? Is a webform the correct way to do this? And how do I make that link between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but no, you are on the wrong track.

Webform module is nice and easy, but it uses it's own storage. And whilst you can indeed use hooks to store a copy in your own table, it would take a pretty huge amount of work to do it properly.

It will be easier if you simply write your own module for that. If you don't know where to start, see [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples).

Comment: Ok, I really thought there would be a customisable module to do this. I have a very basic understanding of drupal but is it easier to write a module than edit hook_query_alter() in the existing webform module if that makes any sense? (I'm quoting something I don't really understand)